# mod_rewrite include slash in URL parmeters

Tags: mod-rewrite, rewrite

Is it possible to include slashes in url parameter rule? Basically I want example.com/hello/world/ to go to example.com?q=hello/world/. Any examples would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: **yes you can include it.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example of a rewrite rule that could accomplish this is:

`RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/?(.+)$ ?q=$1`

This will capture everything after "example.com" and convert it to the q=x form.

I assume you are using Apache in front of some dynamic server-side program, like Tomcat or PHP, because Apache on its own can't really do anything smart with a URL containing a query string.  In this case, you may need to add the [PT] flag to your Rewrite Rule, to ensure that the inbound URL gets rewritten before it is passed along to your dynamic engine.  The rule would then look like:

`RewriteRule ^/?(.+)$ ?q=$1 [PT]`

You should also consider what will happen if your original inbound URL contains a query string of its own.  This example rule will *not* include the inbound query string when it does the rewrite, but you can make it do so with the QSA flag.

Comment: Sorry, I could not get the formatting to work on the first line of code. Those are supposed to be two separate lines, with "RewriteEngine on" as its own line.

Comment: for the formating, you can end 1st line with [enter] and start next line with 4 spaces.